# Clear button on calendar Emberjs

Tags: ember.js, controller, routes, components, action

Adding a clear button for a calendar but I keep receiving "Nothing handled the action" Here is the .hbs file

```
<button class ="clearBtn" {{action "clear"}}> Clear </button>
```

.js controller file

```
   actions: {
      clear(){
          this.set(true, '')
        }
      },
```

What am I missing for the action to be called?

Comment: The code looks fine. Can you reproduce the issue using this twiddle - https://ember-twiddle.com/7a6bd267a523c130b0854992b5ed5145?numColumns=2&openFiles=controllers.application%5C.js%2Ctemplates.application%5C.hbs  so that it will be easy to debug?

Comment: +1 the code looks ok. Some things to confirm: (1) the JS controller file actually corresponds to the hbs file (they should be named the same), (2) the error isn't from a different action. But lastly, if you can, you should use `{{on "click" this.clear}}` instead of the action modifier!